# Vagrantfile hangs on one computer but not on the other

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, vagrant

Here's my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "Svpernova09/homestead-legacy"
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
    config.vm.hostname = "vagrant"
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/root/shared", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]
end
```

It works on one of my machines but not the other. On the one it doesn't work on...  after several minutes I get this:

> Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
>   Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within the
>   configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.
>
> If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that Vagrant
>   had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors are
>   usually good hints as to what may be wrong.
>
> If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
>   working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
>   problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes. Verify
>   that authentication configurations are also setup properly, as well.
>
> If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
>   the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.

If I replace `Svpernova09/homestead-legacy` with `laravel/homestead` it works.

According to `vagrant box list` both machines have the latest version of the box - 0.3.5.

Here's the output of the bad computer:

http://pastebin.com/vMZM6T59

...and of the good computer:

http://pastebin.com/Xx8Mbi4g

I tried rebooting the bad computer to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bad machine had VirtualBox 5.0 installed. Upgrading to VirtualBox 5.1 seems to have fixed the problem.